# Customize UIImagePickerController to have a white border

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I'm trying to reach a controller that looks similar to this:
[image]

Notice the customize size of the capture screen, and the white border around it.
I know, it's impossible to change the background color of UIImagePickerViewController, so im trying to implement an overlayView to go above it.

The main issue is that i need to make a mask view that will show the camera in the middle of the overlay view, and so far i came up short.

Any ideas on how to implement this? How can i easily make a mask view that cuts a "hole" in the overlay view to see the camera underneath it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating your custom camera. It will let you put all sorts of overlays etc. Check out [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/) There is also a bunch of tutorials online describing how to do it very easily. First result from Google search: https://dannygtech.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/custom-camera-on-ios-avcapturesession-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-tutorial/

Comment: Agreed, it would be easier.